# Select MIN decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a scenario where I have duplicate data in a file - where the 'unique' identifiers equal the same.

I am trying to identify which of the decimal values in the 'Outcome1' field is the **MIN** value, which will then give me results which are not duplicated.

I have tried to use **MIN**, but it seems to not work as I have to group by the 'Outcome1' field.

The current table looks like this:

| ID | Outcome1 | Outcome2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 186.5098 | 133.8825 |
| 1 | 186.5093 | 133.8820 |

The expected result is as follows:

| ID | Outcome1 | Outcome2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 186.5093 | 133.8820 |

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Do you want to actual lowest values from each of those columns? Not sure why MIN wouldn't work, that it what is designed for. You would not need, or want, to group by Outcome1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the lowest value from both Outcome1 and Outcome2 you would do this with a basic MIN.

```
select ID
    , Outcome1 = MIN(Outcome1)
    , Outcome2 = MIN(Outcome2)
from YourTable
group by ID
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to consider Outcome1 you can use `row_number`

```
with outcome as (
    select *,
        Row_Number() over(partition by id order by Outcome1 ) rn
    from t
)
select Id, Outcome1, Outcome2
from outcome
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use Row_number() in a partial query and then get the lines that take the number 1

```
select * from (
   SELECT 
   [id]
  ,[Outcome1]
  ,[Outcome2]
  , ROW_NUMBER() over( partition by id order by Outcome1) As RowN
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Table_4]
 ) tt
 where tt.RowN=1
```